# Jquery Accordion - Return to Original State

Tags: jquery, accordion

I've modified an accordion menu I found on CSS Tricks and it's working fine, however...  I'd like for the accordion to return to it's original state when the current (expanded) header is clicked a second time.  So the accordion closes and the original starting width is recognized.

I have the example on codepen...  thanks to anyone willing to take a crack at this! I'm going cross-eyed trying to figure it out.

http://codepen.io/Sektion66/pen/vAGsn

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its working as demo (http://jsfiddle.net/h3Kbu/1/show/) and (http://jsfiddle.net/h3Kbu/1/) for code.Basically `else` part is new code.

```
if (!$el.hasClass("current")) {

        $parentWrap = $el.parent().parent();
        $otherWraps = $(".info-col").not($parentWrap);

        // remove current cell from selection of all cells
        $allTitles = $("dt").not(this);

        // close all info cells
        $allCells.slideUp();

        // return all titles (except current one) to normal size
        $allTitles.animate({
            fontSize: "14px",
            paddingTop: 5,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 5,
            paddingLeft: 12
        });

        // animate current title to larger size            
        $el.animate({
            "font-size": "20px",
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 5,
            paddingLeft: 12
        }).next().slideDown();

        // make the current column the large size
        $parentWrap.animate({
            width: 425
        })

        // make other columns the small size
        $otherWraps.animate({
            width: 250
        })

        // make sure the correct column is current
        $allTitles.removeClass("current");
        $el.addClass("current"); 
    }else{
        $parentWrap = $el.parent().parent();
        $otherWraps = $(".info-col").not($parentWrap);

        // remove current cell from selection of all cells
        $allTitles = $("dt");

        // close all info cells
        $allCells.slideUp();

        // return all titles (except current one) to normal size
        $allTitles.animate({
            fontSize: "14px",
            paddingTop: 5,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 5,
            paddingLeft: 12
        });

        // animate current title to larger size            


        // make the current column the large size
        $parentWrap.animate({
            width: 250
        })

        // make other columns the small size
        $otherWraps.animate({
            width: 250
        })

        // make sure the correct column is current
        $allTitles.removeClass("current");
       // $el.addClass("current"); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'm still learning JQuery, and this helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my crack at it:

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kszyb**

Just added a `else` to your `if (!$el.hasClass("current"))` statement, reversing the element to it's normal state.

Also made these to avoid duplications of the animation states:

```
    var currentState = {
            "font-size": "20px",
            paddingTop: 10,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 5,
            paddingLeft: 12
        };

    var normalState = {
            fontSize: "14px",
            paddingTop: 5,
            paddingRight: 5,
            paddingBottom: 5,
            paddingLeft: 12
        };
```